# Oldsound rabbitmq bundle multiple consumer configuration

Tags: symfony, configuration, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement RabbitMQ with https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle and Symfony2 framework.

I've managed to make the thing work with 1 producer and 1 consumer but the problem is when i use multiple consumers.

This is my configuration:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     'localhost'
            port:     5672
            user:     'guest'
            password: 'guest'
            vhost:    '/'
            lazy:     false
            connection_timeout: 3
            read_write_timeout: 3

            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
            keepalive: false

            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
            heartbeat: 0

            #requires php_sockets.dll
#            use_socket: true # default false
    producers:
        soccer_team_stat:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'soccer_team_stat_qu'}
        soccer_team_stat_form:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: {name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'soccer_team_stat_form_qu'}
    consumers:
        soccer_team_stat:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'soccer_team_stat_qu'}
            callback:         myapp.soccer_team_stat.consume
        soccer_team_stat_form:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'soccer_team_stat_form_qu'}
            callback:         myapp.soccer_team_stat_form.consume
```

Service definitions:

```
  <services>

        <service class="MyApp\EtlBundle\Producers\SoccerTeamStatProducer" id="myapp.soccer_team_stat.produce">
            <argument type="service" id="old_sound_rabbit_mq.soccer_team_stat_producer"/>
        </service>

        <service class="MyApp\EtlBundle\Producers\SoccerTeamStatProducer" id="myapp.soccer_team_stat_form.produce">
            <argument type="service" id="old_sound_rabbit_mq.soccer_team_stat_producer"/>
        </service>

        <service class="MyApp\EtlBundle\Consumers\SoccerTeamStatConsumer" id="myapp.soccer_team_stat.consume">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
        </service>

        <service class="MyApp\EtlBundle\Consumers\SoccerTeamStatFormConsumer" id="myapp.soccer_team_stat_form.consume">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
        </service>

    </services>
```

And on php app/console rabbitmq:consumer -d soccer_team_stat_form i get:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent service
>   "old_sound_rabbit_mq.soccer_team_stat_form_consumer".

I tried various combinations includin using multiple_consumers configuration key but with no success. What i'm i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither of `routing_key` and `binding_key` are set, `direct` exchange will behave like `fanout` and send the messages to all the queues it knows so based on what I'm seeing from your configurations, you are better off using `fanout` so do like below.

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     %rabbit_mq_host%
            port:     %rabbit_mq_port%
            user:     %rabbit_mq_user%
            password: %rabbit_mq_pswd%
            vhost:    /
            lazy:     true
    producers:
        soccer_team_stat:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: fanout }
        soccer_team_stat_form:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: 'soccer_team_stat_form_ex', type: fanout }
    consumers:
        soccer_team_stat:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: 'soccer_team_stat_ex', type: fanout }
            queue_options:    { name: 'soccer_team_stat_qu' }
            callback:         myapp.soccer_team_stat.consume
        soccer_team_stat_form:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: 'soccer_team_stat_form_ex', type: fanout }
            queue_options:    { name: 'soccer_team_stat_form_qu' }
            callback:         myapp.soccer_team_stat_form.consume
```

This [RabbitMQ fanout example with symfony including 2 Producer & 2 Exchange & 2 Queue & N Worker & 2 Consumer](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7zi5/rabbitmq-fanout-example-with-symfony-including-2-producer-2-exchange-2-queue-n-worker-2-consumer) is the full example (*actually the full answer to your question/already made version of what you want to do*) that shows how things are done within symfony apps. I would suggest you to follow the pattern used there. Very easy to follow and maintain. If you want more examples, just search for `RabbitMQ` keyword in that blog.